# \because and \therefore symbols do not follow \boldmath

Tags: amsmath, amssymb

I am having a trouble trying to bold a series of math equations using `\boldmath` command. All equations symbols seem to bold fine except `\because` and `\therefore`. To bold them I have to additionally use extra command like `\pmb` which was not convenient for long sets for equations.

This is a sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

No bold commands used at all (for comparison):
\[ \because x - 1 = 0  \quad \therefore x = 1 \]

Despite using ``boldmath" but No bold ``because" and ``therefore" symbols:
\boldmath
\[ \because x - 1 = 0  \quad \therefore x = 1 \]

To get them bold, ``pmb" must be used:
\[ \pmb \because x - 1 = 0  \quad \pmb \therefore x = 1 \]

\end{document}
```

Which gives the result:

[image]

Other symbols from `amssymb` package (e.g. `\propto`, `\equiv`) followed `\boldmath` without problems.

Is there an alternative command (using `pdflatex` only) that can bold everything in a series of math equation properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AMS amsa and amsb fonts are not available in bold. Other font sets have more complete bold eg the txmath Times Roman style fonts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, newtx}

\begin{document}

No bold commands used at all (for comparison):
\[ \because x - 1 = 0  \quad \therefore x = 1 \]

Despite using ``boldmath" but No bold ``because" and ``therefore" symbols:
\boldmath
\[ \because x - 1 = 0  \quad \therefore x = 1 \]

To get them bold, ``pmb" must be used:
\[ \pmb \because x - 1 = 0  \quad \pmb \therefore x = 1 \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I get this message when I compile `Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log`

Comment: I think I have a problem in my tex installation. The code that you just wrote works fine on Overleaf.

Comment: @hesham try the older form, replace `newtx` by `newtxtext,newtxmath`

Comment: Thanks @David Carlisle I did, but still out of luck. Actually my distribution is up to date and should include `newtx` package. However, neither `newtx` nor `newtxtext, newtxmath` did solve the problem. I still get the above error message.

Comment: The problem was solved by rebuilding the formats in miktex settings. Thank you for your help.